# get exact Value in Setter Property value attribute in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have folllowing resource ResourceDictionary xml file, and I'm trying get `Property="Data"` setter Value in codebehind

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleProject.Layout">

    <!-- User -->
    <Style x:Key="Process" TargetType="Path">        
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M24.5,0 L25.5,0 C39,0 z"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

for that I tried following thing

`var myStyle = (Style)FindResource("User");`

this is getting all the setters and I can get specific setter by like this

```
    var myStyle = (Style)FindResource("Process");

    foreach (var item in myStyle.Setters)
    {
        Setter val2 = (Setter)item;

        if (val2.Property.ToString() == "Data")
        {
          string value =  val2.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

once I debug this I can see, though its actual value `M24.5,0 L25.5,0 C39,0 z` after get this from code behind tht value become `M24.5,0L25.5,0C39,0z`.
which is removed white spaces after `0` ,

how to get exact value without reformat actual value on xaml file ?

Answer (score 0):

> how to get exact value without reformat actual value on xaml file ?

I don't know why you actually need the space or the original `string` but I can tell you that there is no exact `string` value to get efter the XAML processer has parsed the XAML.

It will create a `Geometry` object based on the `string` that you define in the XAML markup and after this there is no `string` to be retrieved any more.

The only way to get the original `string` is to look in the uncompiled source file.

Comment: then how to get values in `in the uncompiled source file` ?

Comment: You could copy the XAML file, set its Build Action to Content and extract the value like you would from any other XML file.